# Angular 2 Form Error : path.split is not a function at <FormArray>this.myForm.get(i)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Trying to make a nested dynamic form in Angular 2.

**Form Skeleton**

```
this.myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
        programmes: this.formBuilder.array([this.initProgramme(),]),
    });

initProgramme() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            tickets: this.formBuilder.array([this.initTicket(),])
        });
    }


initTicket() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            field1:''
        });
    }
```

Adding programme dynamically **works** with following function :-

```
addProgToForm(){

    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('programmes');
        control.push(this.initProgramme());
  }
```

adding ticket to programme **THROWS ERROR**

```
addTicket(programme: any) {
        const control = (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('programmes')).get(programme); // THROWS ERROR  HERE
         (<FormArray>control.get('tickets')).push(this.initTicket());
    }
```

At **.get(programme)** it says **path.split is not a function**

PS - programme in 'get(programme)' is the index of Programme Form Array to which dynamic tickets are to be added. It is retrieved correctly from *ngFor . Example :- index 0 for first programme added.

Answer (score 8):

Try to get control by string index: **.get(programme.toString())**

```
addTicket(programme: any) {
    const control = (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('programmes')).get(programme.toString());
     (<FormArray>control.get('tickets')).push(this.initTicket());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addresses: FormArray;
DynForm: FormGroup;
```

---

```
this.DynForm = formBuild.group({
    firstname: 'Krishna',
    lastName: '',
    addresses: this.address1(),
    Gender: 'Male'
});
```

---

```
address1(): FormArray{
    this.addresses = this.formBuild.array([
        this.addGroup()
    ]);
    return this.addresses;
}

addGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuild.group({
        Street: '',
        Zip: '',
        Country: 'India'
    });
}

add() {
    this.addresses.push(this.addGroup());
}
```

pls try `step ===== !` in angular2 final version

Comment: shouldn't it be this.DynForm.addresses.push(this.addGroup()); instead of  this.addresses.push(this.addGroup());  ? and i can push till level 1 array( i.e address group) , but I have another nested array within this addressgroup , which am not able to access and push.

Answer (score 0):

See https://v8.angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get

```
.get([programme])
```

is the way to go if programme is a number.